# Node js mysql2 - reuse connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm sorry, but I used a translator. I hope you understand.

I got curious while using mysql module. look at the code first.

`db_promise.js`

Create a pool.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const config = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PW,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    connectionLimit: 100,
    queueLimit: 10000,
    multipleStatements: true,
    waitForConnections: true,
    dateStrings: 'date'
}

const createPool = mysql.createPool(config, (err)=>{
    console.error(err);
});

const pool = createPool.promise();

module.exports = pool;
```

`run.js`

`Function A` creates a connection, passes it to `Function B` after use, and continues to use it.

```js
const pool = require('./db_promise.js');

const A = async ()=>{
    let conn;
    try {
        conn = await pool.getConnection();
        await conn.query('do stuff1..');
        await B(conn);
        return;
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        conn.release();
    }
}
const B = async (conn)=>{
    try {
        await conn.query('do stuff2..');
        return;
    }catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

creating connections for each function would be a waste. Can only one connection be reused when it is an associated function?

Comment: You don't need to get and release a connection every time. This is handled by the `pool` feature automatically and the connection is automatically released when the query resolves. Promise functionality is supported as well for queries using a pool connection. More details here: [https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-connection-pools)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Are you saying that I can process queries in multiple functions using only one declared pool? Don't I need to get a new connection when I use transaction?

Comment: Yes. From the module documentation: `The pool does not create all connections upfront but creates them on demand until the connection limit is reached.` The default `connectionLimit` is `10`. If you think you will be executing more than that simultaneously, you should increase the limit number. Simply create the pool, then run queries as needed. I use `mysqljs` (not `mysql2`) but they are effectively the same - [you can see a simple example I have provided previously here](https://github.com/dusthaines/mysqljs_setup_snippet/blob/master/app.js)

Comment: Generally, getConnection can be omitted, but other examples suggest that getConnection must be called in transaction. I learned something new. Thank you and I love you.

Comment: Yes - it can be confusing especially when working with transactions. This is one reason I prefer `mysqljs` over `mysql2` - it [provides a function specifically for transactions](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions). Ultimately `mysql2` will be deprecated and `mysqljs` will be the primary solution for `node`. From the `mysql2` readme: `MySQL2 team is working together with mysqljs/mysql team to factor out shared code and move it under mysqljs organisation`

Comment: 이런.. 실화냐..... a lot of things already depend on mysql2 and it's likely to break down if i change to mysqljs. Let me check it out. Thank you.